# Source code in SoapUI maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, soapui

How I can add my source code ( java code ) to project SoapUI running by maven? I wrote own assertion class and check response in this class. First i made dir ext and put there .jar file. Now I want do the same, but with source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a jar in the `\ext` folder you made the compiled class available to SoapUI test runner.
Instead of that you could include your code as a maven module in your project and add it as dependency. Your Java code should be a maven project for this to work.
A common approach is to create a "modules" directory in your project's root and add your java code in a subdirectory there, let's call it "assertion_module":

```
<root>
 | - soapui-project.xml
 | - pom.xml
 | - modules
      | - assertion_module
           | - src
           | - pom.xml
```

The pom.xml in the  folder should have the necessary properties set, like below (sample values):

```
<groupId>assertion_module</groupId>
<artifactId>assertion_module</artifactId>
<name>assertion_module</name>
<version>0.1</version>
```

In you master `pom.xml`, i.e. the one that you use to run the SoapUI tests declare your assertion module, adding the following:

```
<modules>
    <module>modules/assertion_module</module>
</modules>
```

In the soapui plugin section of this pom add the necessary dependency section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>assertion_module</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertion_module</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    ...
</plugin>
```

Now when you run your tests, the assertion_module will be compiled and be available to SoapUI test runner.
With this you no longer need to add the compiled jar in the `\ext` folder, although you still need to have it in the `<SoapUI_installtion_directory>\bin\ext`.

Comment: Ok, but if i my assertion Java class will be in the other project?

Comment: You should either merge the two projects or install the podule in your local maven repository.

Comment: But master pom.xml will be the same like here?

Comment: You mean if you install your module in your local maven repo? If so, then yes, except that you don't need to to have the `<modules />` section in your pom.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I have 2 maven project. For example projectSoapUI and projectAssertion. In projectSoapUI is pom.xml where i include SoapUI and project. In projectAssertion i have only Java class to assertion response of project (for example test.xml). Tets.xml is of corse in projectSoapUI. And now what are the different from your exmaple?

Comment: How i can install module on asertion project to SoapUI project?

I add depedency to SoapUI sectrion in pom.xml and i dont know what I should do now :/

Comment: Is `projectAssertion` a maven project?

Comment: Yes. In projectAssertion i build on maven .jar file. Also in soapUIproject I add dependency to soapui section and i dont know what i should do now. I use eclipse

Comment: can you share the pom.xml of `projectAssertion` here? To be clear: it is not possible to include your java source code in your soapui project directly.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.asertion</groupId>
  <artifactId>assertion_module</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Some namet</name>
</project>

Comment: run `mvn install` in assertionProject to install the assertion module. Add this dependency in the pom.xml of soapuiProject:
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.asertion</groupId>
 <artifactId>assertion_module</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

That should work. When you change projectAssertion, remember to run `mvn install` again.

Comment: I do this, but doesn't help. This depedency must be at plugin section? Like this:
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
          <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.6.1</version>
          <dependencies>
     <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.asertion</groupId> 
      <artifactId>assertion_module</artifactId> <
      version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
     </dependency> 
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
      </plugin> 
??
The error is that script cant found assertion class

Comment: also my test run like this:

mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test

Comment: My java class is Finder. java. When i put Finder.jar file to dir ext in groovy script i use this class like this : Finder.search(smth). 

Now, i have this class at package so i have to write import to this class? For example com.assertion.Finer.search(smth)? Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Yes! I response to myself. I add the package name to the class name and finally everything is OK. Thank you very much for help.  You had a lot of patience :) Thank you!

Comment: Yup. Glad you sorted this out :)